# Does webpack4 support export esmodule format file?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, babel-loader, esmodules

I know webpack 4 is very old as it's published at 2018. But in my project it's webpack4 still.
And i want to export esmodule format file. So i can use  to load javascript files. And my babel config is like:

```
const morden = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      modules: false,
      targets: {
        esmodules: true
      }
    }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
  ],
  sourceType: 'unambiguous',
  comments: false,
};
```

And webpack config is like:

```
...
output: {
    publicPath,
    path: path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      '../dist/',
      'pro',
      version
    ),
    filename,
  },
...
```

does my config right?

Comment: morden or modern?